# Downloading and setting the classpath for apache classes

Tags: java, apache, classpath

I am refreshing my java knowhow and i want to write and run some code without using any kind of ide.I am doing my development on windows and the location of my java scripts is `C:\java_apps`

I need to test and see how apache `httpclient,httppost,httpresponse and httpentity` work and to do that i need to download the classes first.

I have created a `lib` folder to hopefully house the apache classes.

In my application,i need to import

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

Where can i download the classes and how should i set the classpath for them?.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the classes at the location of your wish. There is no standard location. You just need to set the class path.

**Windows 7:**

From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.

```
Choose Properties from the context menu.
Click the Advanced system settings link.
Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
```

For other veersion of OS please see the [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: So i can download all the apache jars i need,put them under one folder and add that folder to the `;` delimited list of paths?

Comment: I have download http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachehttpcomponentshttpcorejar.htm  jar `httppcore` with all those classes that i require but i still get the same errors.

Comment: I am trying to set the classpath `java -classpath C:\java_apps\lib\apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar` this way.The error is long but it goes `leget.java:3: error: package org.apache.http does not exist
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;`